# How to clear cache in yii2 AR?

Tags: yii2

How to clear that cache of current data?

```
$result = Customer::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return Customer::findOne($id);
}, 60 * 60 * 24 * 4);
```

I want to clear the cache of current data in Customer after updating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify this code to use data cache instead of query cache so you can use unique key.

```
$data = $cache->get('customer' . $id);
if ($data === false) {
    $data = Customer::findOne($id);
    $cache->set('customer' . $id, $data, 60 * 60 * 24 * 4);
}
```

or starting from 2.0.11:

```
$data = $cache->getOrSet('customer' . $id, function () use ($id) {
    return Customer::findOne($id);
}, 60 * 60 * 24 * 4);
```

So now you can use

```
$cache->delete('customer' . $id);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `flush` for global.

```
Yii::$app->cache->flush();
```

you can use `TagDependency` :

```
$result = Customer::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return Customer::findOne($id);
}, 60 * 60 * 24 * 4, new TagDependency(['tags'=>'customer']));

//to flush
TagDependency::invalidate(Yii::$app->cache, 'customer');
```

For more information check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-tagdependency.html)

Comment: Did I understand correctly? for current $id I can add  `new TagDependency(['tags'=>'customer-' . $id]`, and after then flush `TagDependency::invalidate(Yii::$app->cache, 'customer-' . $id);`

Comment: did you try like that?

Comment: yes and it doesnt worked for me((, I dont want to flush all caches. Only for current $id of customer